# Windows Server 2008 R2 Port Rules

Tags: windows-server-2008, port, node.js

We have a node installed on a Windows Server 2008 that should be listening to port:3000. When we hit the page while on the server everything works as it should but... when we try to hit the same page from another machine it we get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. I have added a new rule in the Server Manager->Configure->Windows Firewall wutg Advanced Security->Inbound Rules.

**With the following settings:**

```
Name: Node Express App 
Profile: All 
Enabled: Yes 
Action: Allow 
Override: No 
Program: Any 
Local Address: Any 
Remote Address: Any 
Protocol: TCP 
Local Port: 3000 
Remote Port: 3000 
Allowed Users: Any 
Allowed Computers: Any
```

I have tried using an online tool yougetsignal.com to hit my server IP at the 3000 port and it returns `Port 3000 is closed on xxx.xx.x.x(server ip)`

Not sure what next steps might be to help? Do these rule changes require restarts? Any feedback would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The remote port from the client connecting to the server is not going to be port 3000, it's going to be an ephemeral port. Set the remote port in your rule to `All Ports`.